# Cannot open .cshtml files in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Few days ago I have updated my Visual Studio 2015 with Asp.NET 5 RC1 and today I have found out that I cannot open .cshtml files.

Has anyone encountered this behaviour?

When I doubleclick the file, it shows me an error alert saying "The operation could not be completed".

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio 2015? [After Visual Studio is installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#Anchor_6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem but the latest Windows 10 update yesterday solved the problem here. Can you check for updates?

Comment: Thanks, now I cannot work because my virtual machine is doing a super long update :D

Comment: However, the time was worthy - it really works. Thanks

Comment: Any specifics on which update fixed your issue? I'm experiencing the same issue but seem to have applied all windows 10 updates with no luck

Answer (score 1):

For those whose issue isn't resolved by running Windows Update, instead manually install Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx).

Not sure why Windows Update didn't install that for me... :(

Comment: I have windows 8 and this solution works for me. Windows update didn't install that.Thanks.